# make each thumbnail correspond with display image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this image slider up to this level and I think I need some help.

I created an image slider with arrows, and thumbnails at the bottom of the display slider. The display slider works just fine, only that from the JavaScript code I've written, I can't seem to make each thumbnail correspond with the display image slider.

My intention for this slider to work was that: *when a thumbnail is clicked, it would reflect in the display slider*. Also, *when the left or right arrow of the display slider is clicked, the corresponding thumbnail becomes active*. And finally, with a fade transitioning, maybe?

See the code I wrote:

```js
let leftArrow = document.querySelector('#slide_left')
let rightArrow = document.querySelector('#slide_right')
let slidesContainer = document.querySelector('#slides')

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const last = document.querySelector('#slides > :last-child');
  last.remove();
  slidesContainer.prepend(last);
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const first = document.querySelector('#slides > :first-child');
  first.remove();
  slidesContainer.append(first);
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

div#slides_wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #efefef;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div#slides_wrapper div#slides {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #0ff3;
}

img.slide {
  width: 100%;
}

img.thumbnail {
  width: 50px;
}

div.slide_arrow {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
}

div.slide_arrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.slide_arrow#slide_left {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

div.slide_arrow#slide_right {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

div#thumbnails {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div#thumbnails img.thumbnail {
  background-color: #888;
  margin: 5px;
}

div#thumbnails img.thumbnail:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div#thumbnails img.thumbnail.active {
  border: 2px solid #0ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_wrapper">
  <div id="slides_wrapper">
    <div id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow"><span>&#10094;</span></div>
    <div id="slides">
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1564149/pexels-photo-1564149.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/783243/pexels-photo-783243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4066293/pexels-photo-4066293.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/428340/pexels-photo-428340.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9558760/pexels-photo-9558760.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5701644/pexels-photo-5701644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow"><span>&#10095;</span></div>
  </div>
  <div id="thumbnails">
    <img class="thumbnail active" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1564149/pexels-photo-1564149.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/783243/pexels-photo-783243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4066293/pexels-photo-4066293.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/428340/pexels-photo-428340.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9558760/pexels-photo-9558760.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5701644/pexels-photo-5701644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please feel free to alter the code, if need be. I really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of found a way to make it fade based on David Y's answer. To be a bit more precise as to how I achieved it. All the changes I made were in the CSS. Setting the immediate container of the image slides to the position of relative and the slides themselves to the position of absolute. Also, using the top, left, width, and height properties to make them stay in the container. As well as the z-index property for opacity I guess.

```js
let leftArrow = document.querySelector("#img_slide_left");
let rightArrow = document.querySelector("#img_slide_right");
let slidesContainer = document.querySelector("#img_slides");

let applyThumbnail = function(dataIdx) {
  document.querySelector("#img_thumbnails > img.active").classList.remove("active");
  document.querySelector(`#img_thumbnails > [data-index='${parseInt(dataIdx)}']`).classList.add("active");
};

let thumbnailClick = function(dataIdx) {
  document.querySelector("#img_thumbnails > img.active").classList.remove("active");
  document.querySelector(`#img_thumbnails > [data-index='${parseInt(dataIdx)}']`).classList.add("active");
  document.querySelector(`#img_slides > img.active`).classList.remove("active");
  document.querySelector(`#img_slides > [data-index='${parseInt(dataIdx)}']`).classList.add("active");
};

leftArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const currentActive = document.querySelector("#img_slides > img.active");
  const prevSibling = currentActive.previousElementSibling;

  currentActive.classList.remove("active");

  if (prevSibling) {
    // Select Prev Image
    prevSibling.classList.add("active");
    applyThumbnail(prevSibling.getAttribute("data-index"));
  } else {
    // Select Last Image
    const last = document.querySelector("#img_slides > :last-child");
    last.classList.add("active");
    applyThumbnail(last.getAttribute("data-index"));
  }
});

rightArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const currentActive = document.querySelector("#img_slides > img.active");
  const nextSibling = currentActive.nextElementSibling;

  currentActive.classList.remove("active");

  if (nextSibling) {
    // Select Next Image
    nextSibling.classList.add("active");
    applyThumbnail(nextSibling.getAttribute("data-index"));
  } else {
    // Select First Image
    const first = document.querySelector("#img_slides > :first-child");
    first.classList.add("active");
    applyThumbnail(first.getAttribute("data-index"));
  }
});

document.querySelectorAll(".imgThumbnail").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    thumbnailClick(this.getAttribute("data-index"));
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

div#img_slides_wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #efefef;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

div#img_slides_wrapper div#img_slides {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #0ff3;
}

img.imgSlide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 750ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

img.imgSlide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.imgThumbnail {
  width: 50px;
}

div.img_slide_arrow {
  color: transparent;
  height: inherit;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

div.img_slide_arrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.img_slide_arrow:hover>span {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #00000033;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

div.img_slide_arrow#img_slide_left {}

div.img_slide_arrow#img_slide_right {
  right: 0;
}

div.img_slide_arrow#img_slide_left span {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

div.img_slide_arrow#img_slide_right span {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  right: 0;
}

div#img_thumbnails {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div#img_thumbnails img.imgThumbnail {
  background-color: #888;
  margin: 5px;
}

div#img_thumbnails img.imgThumbnail:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div#img_thumbnails img.imgThumbnail.active {
  border: 2px solid #0ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_wrapper">
  <div id="img_slides_wrapper">
    <div id="img_slide_left" class="img_slide_arrow"><span>&#10094;</span></div>
    <div id="img_slides">
      <img data-index="0" class="imgSlide active" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1564149/pexels-photo-1564149.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img data-index="1" class="imgSlide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/783243/pexels-photo-783243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img data-index="2" class="imgSlide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4066293/pexels-photo-4066293.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img data-index="3" class="imgSlide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/428340/pexels-photo-428340.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img data-index="4" class="imgSlide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9558760/pexels-photo-9558760.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img data-index="5" class="imgSlide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5701644/pexels-photo-5701644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img data-index="6" class="imgSlide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1639729/pexels-photo-1639729.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img data-index="7" class="imgSlide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4965343/pexels-photo-4965343.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="img_slide_right" class="img_slide_arrow"><span>&#10095;</span></div>
  </div>

  <div id="img_thumbnails">
    <img data-index="0" class="imgThumbnail active" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1564149/pexels-photo-1564149.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img data-index="1" class="imgThumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/783243/pexels-photo-783243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img data-index="2" class="imgThumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4066293/pexels-photo-4066293.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img data-index="3" class="imgThumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/428340/pexels-photo-428340.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img data-index="4" class="imgThumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9558760/pexels-photo-9558760.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img data-index="5" class="imgThumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5701644/pexels-photo-5701644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img data-index="6" class="imgThumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1639729/pexels-photo-1639729.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img data-index="7" class="imgThumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4965343/pexels-photo-4965343.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Just thought it was okay to share my petite knowledge. :)

Comment: Since you won't be re-assigning the variables "leftArrow", "rightArrow", "slidesContainer", "applyThumbnail", and "thumbnailClick" then declare them as "const" instead of "let".

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `data` attribute to help with indexing. I add a listener to the thumbnail so it displays the corresponding image.

```js
let leftArrow = document.querySelector("#slide_left");
let rightArrow = document.querySelector("#slide_right");
let slidesContainer = document.querySelector("#slides");

let applyThumbnail = function (dataIdx) {
  document.querySelector("#thumbnails > img.active").classList.remove("active");
  document
    .querySelector(`#thumbnails > [data-index='${parseInt(dataIdx)}']`)
    .classList.add("active");
};

let thumbnailClick = function (dataIdx) {
  document.querySelector("#thumbnails > img.active").classList.remove("active");
  document
    .querySelector(`#thumbnails > [data-index='${parseInt(dataIdx)}']`)
    .classList.add("active");
  document.querySelector(`#slides > img.active`).classList.remove("active");
  document
    .querySelector(`#slides > [data-index='${parseInt(dataIdx)}']`)
    .classList.add("active");
};

leftArrow.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const currentActive = document.querySelector("#slides > img.active");
  const prevSibling = currentActive.previousElementSibling;
  currentActive.classList.remove("active");
  if (prevSibling) {
    // Select Prev Image
    prevSibling.classList.add("active");
    applyThumbnail(prevSibling.getAttribute("data-index"));
  } else {
    // Select Last Image
    const last = document.querySelector("#slides > :last-child");
    last.classList.add("active");
    applyThumbnail(last.getAttribute("data-index"));
  }
});

rightArrow.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const currentActive = document.querySelector("#slides > img.active");
  const nextSibling = currentActive.nextElementSibling;
  currentActive.classList.remove("active");
  if (nextSibling) {
    // Select Next Image
    nextSibling.classList.add("active");
    applyThumbnail(nextSibling.getAttribute("data-index"));
  } else {
    // Select First Image
    const first = document.querySelector("#slides > :first-child");
    first.classList.add("active");
    applyThumbnail(first.getAttribute("data-index"));
  }
});

document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail").forEach(function (elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function () {
    thumbnailClick(this.getAttribute("data-index"));
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

div#slides_wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #efefef;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div#slides_wrapper div#slides {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #0ff3;
}

img.slide {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

img.slide.active {
  display: block;
}

img.thumbnail {
  width: 50px;
}

div.slide_arrow {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
}

div.slide_arrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.slide_arrow#slide_left {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

div.slide_arrow#slide_right {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

div#thumbnails {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div#thumbnails img.thumbnail {
  background-color: #888;
  margin: 5px;
}

div#thumbnails img.thumbnail:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div#thumbnails img.thumbnail.active {
  border: 2px solid #0ff;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main_wrapper">
      <div id="slides_wrapper">
        <div id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow"><span>&#10094;</span></div>
        <div id="slides">
          <img
            data-index="0"
            class="slide active"
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1564149/pexels-photo-1564149.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            data-index="1"
            class="slide"
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/783243/pexels-photo-783243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            data-index="2"
            class="slide"
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4066293/pexels-photo-4066293.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            data-index="3"
            class="slide"
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/428340/pexels-photo-428340.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            data-index="4"
            class="slide"
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9558760/pexels-photo-9558760.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            data-index="5"
            class="slide"
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5701644/pexels-photo-5701644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
        <div id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow"><span>&#10095;</span></div>
      </div>
      <div id="thumbnails">
        <img
          data-index="0"
          class="thumbnail active"
          src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1564149/pexels-photo-1564149.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
          alt=""
        />
        <img
          data-index="1"
          class="thumbnail"
          src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/783243/pexels-photo-783243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
          alt=""
        />
        <img
          data-index="2"
          class="thumbnail"
          src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4066293/pexels-photo-4066293.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
          alt=""
        />
        <img
          data-index="3"
          class="thumbnail"
          src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/428340/pexels-photo-428340.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
          alt=""
        />
        <img
          data-index="4"
          class="thumbnail"
          src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9558760/pexels-photo-9558760.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
          alt=""
        />
        <img
          data-index="5"
          class="thumbnail"
          src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5701644/pexels-photo-5701644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just dropped the bomb by answering the question "precisely as I wanted it". The thing is, What if there were multiple images? Would there be a need to give each image a "data-attribute"? That's a bit stressful don't you think? I had lots of images to put in here, only that, Stack Overflow doesn't allow too much code.

Comment: Can you do the exact thing you just did without data-attribute? Pleeeaase

Comment: I think if you add the event listener by using loop with each different 'index' inside it the function, and using selector `:nth-child()`. You can achieve it for the thumbnail, but not for the arrow listener (except you have global currentIndex). But I think data-attribute is not a bad idea to make a slider, I usually use this slider library https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and from this library,it used the 'data-attribute' too, that is my reference for this solution.

Comment: and Actually you can use javascript to add the 'data-attribute' by looping for example #slides children and add the attribute 0,1,2,3,4,5 . so you don't need to write that index manually

Comment: Could you help me do that please?

Comment: Also, could you help me add a fade transitioning for the display image? Don't want to feel like I'm asking too much. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Mr. David sir, really sorry to bother you and sorry I didn't mark this as the correct answer soon enough. I utilised this answer to amicable result in what I was trying to develop. By "utilised your answer", I mean, since I used this answer in my code, you could be of ideal aid in helping me solve this please, please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727931/sandbox-modal-in-sandbox

Answer (score 1):

### Step

1. You need to get list of thumbnails and set active number variable to put initial
   number of thumbnail shown
2. When user click left, decrement the active number and set it to length of thumbails when reach lowest value
3. When user click right, increment the active number and reset it when reach lowest value.
4. Each click will clean current active class first

### CODE:

```js
let leftArrow = document.querySelector('#slide_left')
let rightArrow = document.querySelector('#slide_right')

let slidesContainer = document.querySelector('#slides')
let thumbnailContainer = document.querySelector('#thumbnails')

let thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')
let activeThumbnailNumber = 0

const removeAllActiveThumbnail = () => {
  for (let index = 0; index < thumbnails.length; index++) {
    thumbnails[index].classList.remove("active");; 
  }
}

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const lastSlide = document.querySelector('#slides > :last-child');
  lastSlide.remove();
  slidesContainer.prepend(lastSlide);
 
  if (activeThumbnailNumber == 0) {
    activeThumbnailNumber = thumbnails.length -1
  } else {
    activeThumbnailNumber--
  }
  removeAllActiveThumbnail()
  thumbnails[activeThumbnailNumber].classList.add('active')
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const firstSlide = document.querySelector('#slides > :first-child');
  firstSlide.remove();
  slidesContainer.append(firstSlide);
  
  if (activeThumbnailNumber === thumbnails.length -1) {
    activeThumbnailNumber = 0
  } else {
    activeThumbnailNumber++
  }
  removeAllActiveThumbnail()
  thumbnails[activeThumbnailNumber].classList.add('active')
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

div#slides_wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #efefef;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div#slides_wrapper div#slides {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #0ff3;
}

img.slide {
  width: 100%;
}

img.thumbnail {
  width: 50px;
}

div.slide_arrow {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
}

div.slide_arrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.slide_arrow#slide_left {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

div.slide_arrow#slide_right {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

div#thumbnails {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div#thumbnails img.thumbnail {
  background-color: #888;
  margin: 5px;
}

div#thumbnails img.thumbnail:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div#thumbnails img.thumbnail.active {
  border: 2px solid #0ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_wrapper">
  <div id="slides_wrapper">
    <div id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow"><span>&#10094;</span></div>
    <div id="slides">
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1564149/pexels-photo-1564149.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/783243/pexels-photo-783243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4066293/pexels-photo-4066293.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/428340/pexels-photo-428340.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9558760/pexels-photo-9558760.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
      <img class="slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5701644/pexels-photo-5701644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow"><span>&#10095;</span></div>
  </div>
  <div id="thumbnails">
    <img class="thumbnail active" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1564149/pexels-photo-1564149.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/783243/pexels-photo-783243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4066293/pexels-photo-4066293.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/428340/pexels-photo-428340.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9558760/pexels-photo-9558760.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5701644/pexels-photo-5701644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One more thing sir. I would also like when you click a thumbnail it shows in the display. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you still there? :(

Comment: You can add "click" event listener when thumbnail-1 for example clicked, show slide-1. thumbnail-1 and slide-1 are an id you can put in your thumbnail and slide element